Contact with Unspecified Source
In Marketing Cloud there are some contacts with the source Unspecified. Moreover, those contacts have ExactTarget (0) as Type. Does anybody know the meaning of these values for those parameters? I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Unspecified contacts are contacts with no channel. IMHO, they normally come from Synchronized Data Extensions.
Salesforce also lists scenarios that will populate this Unspecified contact Here:


Contacts found in Populations that have not been sent to yet.
Contacts added via Synchronized Data Sources that have not yet been sent to.
Push Devices added by a poor implementation of the iOS SDK or Android SDK.
Push Devices that have gone from unidentifiable (pre-setContactKey function) to identifiable (after setContactKey establishes a Contact).
Using any of the /contacts/v1 routes without specifying a channel
When a new Contact is injected into a Journey within Journey Builder, but is not sent to.
When a Business Unit utilizes any Mobile Studio Product - These Subscribers will only show the Mobile Number, Device ID, or OTT Name when viewed in the BU
When an email subscriber is deleted in Email Studio (not using Contacts Delete)


I am not sure regarding the type is ExactTarget (0), it seems all contacts in MC will have this type value.
